# Проблема с обработкой большого диапазона адресов

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Пишу проект по типу advanced ip scanner.

Возникла проблема с обработкой большого диапазона адресов. 
Допустим, у меня есть список адресов, их 3000, мне нужно вывести их в List по 100 штук в отдельном потоке, и, соответственно, пингануть их. Помогите пожалуйста реализовать поток. Ну или подскажите как еще это можно сделать. При одновременном выводе всех значений программа просто виснет и все.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте:

1. Несколько потоков.
2. Очередь.
3. Ещё одну очередь.
4. Ещё один поток.

В очередь помещайте очередной ip. Каждый поток выбирает из очереди ip и пинает его. Результат помещает во вторую очередь. Ещё один поток выбирает эти результаты и выводит куда Вам надо.

Очередь представляет коллекцию объектов, основанную на принципе "первым вошёл — первым вышел". Один поток может ставить чего-нибудь в очередь, другой принимать.

```
// q очередь ip для пингования
BlockingCollection<IP> q = new BlockingCollection<IP>(new ConcurrentQueue<IP>());
List<IP> ipList = ...;

// Здесь должен быть код запуска потоков-пинговальщиков

// В основном потоке ставить в очередь
foreach (IP ip in ipList) {
    q.Add(ip);
}
q.Add(null); // Используем null в качестве терминатора

// Здесь должен быть код ожидания завершения потоков
```

В потоках пинговальщиках:

```
while(true) {
    IP ip = q.Take(); // Извлекает очередной ip из очереди. Ждёт если в очереди ничего нет
    if (ip == null) break; // Получен терминатор, ip больше не будет, завершить работу
    String pingResult = ping(ip);
    Console.WriteLn(pingResult);
}
q.Add(null); // Вернуть терминатор в очередь. Ведь мы его извлекли, другие потоки не увидят и не закончатся никогда
```

С 3 и 4 Можно не извращаться. В потоке полностью сформировать строку отчёта и записать куда надо (например вывести на консоль).

Comment: Могли бы на примере показать. не очень понял с очередью

Comment: @ИгнатМедведский см. обновленный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, попробою

Comment: Блокировка с ответа снята. Пожалуйста, оставьте его именно в таком виде.